# Firebase direct child vs nested child changed events

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In Firebase **Structure Your Data** section, there is a talk about the below example where chat messages are stored under chat conversation ids.

On considering this particular scenario, we have chat `one` under `messages` and all messages are stored under that like `m1`, `m2` etc.

Now when User is on home screen, it should list all the conversations, he/she is a part of. And in any of that, a new messages arrives the UI will update to show the new messages. But for that we need to bind listeners to each conversation like: `onChildAdded` for `one`, `onChildAdded` for `two` and so on.

How can I listen to an `onChildAdded` for any conversation ? Setting `onChildUpdate` on `messages` will send DataSnapshot of including all the conversations. If there are huge records, that would not be feasible. And finding which child of that whole snapshot is actually updated is a pain.

If I choose to store messages directly under the `messages` while each message contains `conversationId` field to check where it belongs to. By creating `indexOn` on `conversationId`, I can keep an eye on every child added or updated by setting a value listener for `messages`. But there might be performance issue with a very large database I think.

The need for updating any child is because I need to do some calculations for statistics of messages.

Is it possible to achieve this kind of situational? I need to keep an eye on just synced data for each conversation regardless of position where the user is in the app (Setting up the listener in the Application class might be the good option for this) to update multiple values somewhere else.

The data I am referring to is this:

```
{
  // Chats contains only meta info about each conversation
  // stored under the chats's unique ID
  "chats": {
    "one": {
      "title": "Historical Tech Pioneers",
      "lastMessage": "ghopper: Relay malfunction found. Cause: moth.",
      "timestamp": 1459361875666
    },
    "two": { ... },
    "three": { ... }
  },

  // Conversation members are easily accessible
  // and stored by chat conversation ID
  "members": {
    // we'll talk about indices like this below
    "one": {
      "ghopper": true,
      "alovelace": true,
      "eclarke": true
    },
    "two": { ... },
    "three": { ... }
  },

  // Messages are separate from data we may want to iterate quickly
  // but still easily paginated and queried, and organized by chat
  // conversation ID
  "messages": {
    "one": {
      "m1": {
        "name": "eclarke",
        "message": "The relay seems to be malfunctioning.",
        "timestamp": 1459361875337
      },
      "m2": { ... },
      "m3": { ... }
    },
    "two": { ... },
    "three": { ... }
  }
}
```

Comment: So have you found a solution for your problem?

Comment: @user2924714 Nop.. I try to check and update the data when user enters a one chat. If user exit the chat, stop listening for changes on that node. Nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need to register listeners for all chat nodes **{one, two, three, etc}**. Better if you listen parent node to listen all childs **one, two, three, etc**.

Imagine your first screen is a list of the chat rooms which contains basic info like **title, last message, timestamp**. It is better if you register a child event listener for **/chats/** node. So you can get a list of all chat items. When a user click on a chat item for example **/chats/one/**, register a child event listener for **/messages/one/** and **/members/one/** node for members that belong to this chat.

Comment: I know I can do that. But I want to set a listener for all the messages inside `messages`. Even if user has opened chat `one` there should be a listener in the background which should listen to all the messages..

Comment: if you dont kill your activity when to start messages activity it will keep listening

Comment: you should removelistener to make it stop listening

Comment: Not when the activity open.. So for example, in any of the message conversations, a message arrives regardless of the conversation. I can listen that in Application class. But how can I accurately get the new child on all the message conversations from the Application class (that would be good place to listen regardless of the activity).

Comment: Ok. As i understood you want to listen if there re any new messages which belong to any conversations. Btw conversations and messages are related.  If there are no conversation, there will be no messages. So you cannot say a message regardless of conversation. But if you mean to listen any new messages then just register child event listener to /messages/ node. Whenever a message is added, removed, moved or changed an event will be triggered. For ex. imagine first you have no messages and then 1 msg arrived then you will write it to messages/one node and onChildAdded event will be triggered.

Comment: Yes, that is the confusion here. Considering a scenario, You set a listener for `messages`. And there are child as `one`, `two`, `three` etc. So if a new message arrives in say conversation one, I will get a `childChanged` callback because its direct child `one` is changed with a new data and in a data snapshot I will get the whole `one` conversation, from which I won't be able to identify what happened inside `one`

Comment: Aha ok. You should use a list List<ChildEventListener> listeners; and add listeners for each child messages/one, messages/two, etc. when a conversation is  removed, remove listener also.

Comment: Isn't there any better option? Or using a single listener for multiple paths? Anything like that?

Comment: I dont think single listener for multiple paths is possible. But it works fine with adding listeners for all childs. If you think it will get bigger by the time. you should change you rdata structure to constrain the messages. For example adding a city id to the path will constrain the listeners (i.e. messages/cityId/one). i dont think a user will need to see tons of messages at the same time. Show them what they need. and restructure your data accordingly.

Comment: User may not be interacting with all messages, but i need to pre-process all the messages before user tries to see them. To calculate and update the some stats for the messages and add some new properties..